# jQuery click() only once

Tags: jquery

I want to make it so that this button can be clicked only once. If someone clicks it more times then the function will not be performed. How can I do that?

```js
$(".btn_ranking").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
  var time = localStorage.getItem('timer_end');

  $.ajax({
    url: "php/file.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      name: name,
      time: time
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `one()` to attach the event handler:

```js
$(".btn_ranking").one('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
  var time = localStorage.getItem('timer_end');

  $.ajax({
    url: "php/file.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      name: name,
      time: time
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rory's answer, you can also do one of these:

I can't tell from your code here what your markup is, but if your `.btn_ranking` element is a `<button />` tag, then in your click function you can also add a `disabled` attribute to the button, which should prevent it from being clicked again.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp

Another thing you can do is add an inline style to that same element of `pointer-events: none;`

A caveat for ALL of these solutions is that they can be circumvented by simply refreshing the browser.