# Count Click Only Once

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      var clicks = 0;
      function clickME() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
      }    
    </script>

    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
    <button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to use this example I found:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Single click JS Button</h1>
  <button type="submit" onClick="this.disabled = true; return true;">Submit</button>
</body>
```

I'm confused on how to use the `onClick="this.disabled = true;` part because for my code I already have the function called when I wrote onClick. I used `onClick="clickMe()`.

Are you allowed to have `onClick` twice? I want to use the `onClick="this.disabled = true;` because I don't want to keep increasing the amount of clicks if the user clicks the button again. If they click it once I only want to increment once and then disable the button or just not increase the count after.

### Note on possible duplicate

I do not think this is a duplicate of the other question, as that is jQuery click() only once, but I'm using JavaScript. I have not learned jQuery ([jQuery click() only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403168/jquery-click-only-once))*

Comment: https://www.includehelp.com/code-snippets/javascript-disable-button-after-click-using-function.aspx

Comment: You need to use return false inside submit button or it will submit form and forget you js counter. Otherwise you can use button type instead of submit type.

Comment: @bestinamir I'm not using the submit button in my code. My code is the the snippet above the one you're referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look here:

```js
var clicks = 0;
function clickME(el) {
   el.disabled = true;
   clicks += 1;
   document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

```html
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
<button type="button" onClick="clickME(this)">Click me</button>
<button type="button" onClick="clickME(this)">Click me</button>
<button type="button" onClick="clickME(this)">Click me</button>
<button type="button" onClick="clickME(this)">Click me</button>
```

Comment: @YousefTukachinsky Can you please explain why I need (this) and what el means?

Comment: `this` refer to the element which cause the event. you need it to make this element `disabled`

Comment: I'm still confused on what the el is doing, I know el in javascript is just a identifier that is referring to an element but why don't I need multiple el's? The way I'm understanding it is that the el is an identifier for only one button. I have multiple so don't I need that statement for each button?

Comment: the function receive the element as a parameter, and make it disabled. every button send itself as a parameter, so when he call the function, the function make *him* disabled

Comment: you not need this for each button. you not need anything more then what you see in the snipped above

Comment: one last thing, how does the code know that the el is referring to the button? I have not used parameters that much, I'm still fairly new to javascript. Also thank you for explaining the code so far.

Comment: the element call the function, and pass there `this` as a parameter. `this` refer to the calling object. in our case it is the element. so the `el` that passed to the element is the `this` or the calling element

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener` option `once:true` - looks like a perfect option in your case.

More explanations in the code

```js
var clicks = 0
function clickME(event) {
  clicks += 1

  document.getElementById("clicks").innerText = clicks // innerText is more suitable in this case

  if (event.target.className.includes(`auto-disable`)) {
    event.target.disabled = true // auto disabling if you need it
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll(`button`) // select all buttons
  .forEach( // loop through the elements
    // addEventListener with options once:true. once option designed exactly for your purposes, to fire event only once
    el => el.addEventListener(`click`, clickME, {once: true})
  )
```

```html
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
<button type="button">Click me</button>
<button type="button" class="auto-disable">Click me</button>
<button type="button" class="auto-disable">Click me</button>
```